# using a pointer without referencing?

Tags: c, pointers

i have a problem with this function this function using a pointer without referencing it but I surprised that it working and I don't know why ptr in the Function is not referenced and function working without error if any person can explain me why it not generate error i'll be so grateful

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * Ret(int *x)
{
    int *ptr;
    *ptr = (-1*(*x));
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int val = 5,op;
    op = *Ret(&val);
    printf("%d",op);
}
```

output will be -5 but I think that it must generate run time error ?

Comment: Your code exhibits Undefined Behaviour. You are unlucky that an error did not appear

Comment: you need to enable all the compiler warnings.  Then you would see a warning that a int* is being saved to a int.  Also, the function Ret() is returning a pointer to an item on the stack.  Any item on the stack is invalid after the scope of that item (in this case the function Ret()) is exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour.

Anything can happen and because of that can be a valid behaviour.

If you want to catch these problems use external tools, e.g. `valgrind` or a custom compiler e.g. `clang` with address sanitizer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the fact that the function is doing something wrong.
The function returns a pointer to an integer which is allocated only inside the function.
The memory (the value) the pointer points to does not change at the end of the function and this is why you get the correct value. (the implementation of C allows it)

if you had more function later on, they might have override this memory and the value of 'op' might have changed

Bottom line, don't do it!

Comment: the language doesn't allow this. the compiler implementation did, just because he was lucky. you cannot and shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: Thanks, I rephrased the answer.

Answer (score 0):

int *ptr is on the stack. Stack variables are not initialized. So it can have any value. The *ptr= assignment dereferences ptr, that is, the "any value" is taken as an address and the right hand side is stored there. If "any value", as an address, is outside the program's assigned memory, a run time error will ocur. Otherwise some memory of the program is overwritten; this error can become manifest at any later moment, can not manifest itself at all, or can give (noted or unnoted) wrong results. "Bad code", in summary.

The compiler could catch the error by flagging the use of ptr as use of an uninitialized variable.